MVC tests not working after updates in Java and SpringBoot
I performed some updates in an aplication: Java 11 -> 17, and the SpringBoot version is now 3.2.10.
Because of this changes I had to stop using javax* imports and started using jakarta*. Another change I did was going from springfox to spring-doc dependencies.
With all this changes my MVC tests stopped working, it seems to be an autentication problem. Here is one of the tests failing:
class CartControllerMvcTest {

    @MockBean
    private CartSimulationService cartService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private static final String PATH = "/v2/cart";

    @Test
    void shouldSimulateValidCartWhenStatus2xx() throws Exception {
        final CartRequest cartRequestMock = CartRequestMockBuilder.getBuilder().mockCartRequest().build();
        final CartSimulationDTO cartSimulationDTOMock = CartSimulationDTOMockBuilder.mock();
        final CartResponse cartResponseMock = CartResponseMockBuilder.getBuilder()
                .mockCartResponse(true, false).build();

        when(cartService.simulation(cartSimulationDTOMock)).thenReturn(cartResponseMock);

        final MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(post(PATH)
                .header("country", MOCKED_COUNTRY)
                .header("requestTraceId", MOCKED_REQUEST_TRACE_ID)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(cartRequestMock)))
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful()).andReturn();

        String response = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertThat(response).isEqualTo(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(cartResponseMock));
    }

Also I have a SecurityConfig class with the CSRF disable. My pom.xml has the following dependencies:
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.shared.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <version>${org.jacoco.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
            <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
            <version>${javatuples.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
            <artifactId>togglz-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
            <artifactId>togglz-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>newrelic-agent</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>newrelic-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- contract tests dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

Here are the logs of when I start the application

      :: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT :: 
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:09.657-0300","level":"INFO","message":"HV000001: Hibernate Validator 8.0.1.Final","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"background-preinit"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:09.715-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Starting ErpConnectorVipServiceApplication using Java 17.0.12 with PID 25564 (C:\\Users\\melissap\\Desktop\\Projetos\\us-integration-erp-connector-vip\\target\\classes started by melissap in C:\\Users\\melissap\\Desktop\\Projetos\\us-integration-erp-connector-vip)","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:09.722-0300","level":"INFO","message":"The following 2 profiles are active: \"item\", \"cosmos\"","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:13.326-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:13.560-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 221 ms. Found 0 MongoDB repository interfaces.","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:15.844-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:15.867-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Initializing ProtocolHandler [\"http-nio-8080\"]","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:15.873-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Starting service [Tomcat]","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:15.874-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.30]","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:16.148-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:16.151-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5888 ms","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:18.264-0300","level":"INFO","message":"MongoClient with metadata {\"driver\": {\"name\": \"mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-boot\", \"version\": \"4.11.4\"}, \"os\": {\"type\": \"Windows\", \"name\": \"Windows 11\", \"architecture\": \"amd64\", \"version\": \"10.0\"}, \"platform\": \"Java/JetBrains s.r.o./17.0.12+1-b1207.37\"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=majority, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=null, transportSettings=null, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.mongodb.MongoMetricsCommandListener@188058fb], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, CollectionCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.client.model.mql.ExpressionCodecProvider@1028a747, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@24890021, com.mongodb.KotlinCodecProvider@613ba54e]}, loggerSettings=LoggerSettings{maxDocumentLength=1000}, clusterSettings={hosts=[localhost:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='15 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.mongodb.MongoMetricsConnectionPoolListener@769f6023], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=JAVA_LEGACY, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, dnsClient=null, inetAddressResolver=null, contextProvider=null}","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:18.314-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=65176400}","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"cluster-ClusterId{value='67509f7eedf9dd162a7a5882', description='null'}-localhost:27017"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:19.265-0300","level":"INFO","message":"MongoClient with metadata {\"driver\": {\"name\": \"mongo-java-driver|sync\", \"version\": \"4.11.4\"}, \"os\": {\"type\": \"Windows\", \"name\": \"Windows 11\", \"architecture\": \"amd64\", \"version\": \"10.0\"}, \"platform\": \"Java/JetBrains s.r.o./17.0.12+1-b1207.37\"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=majority, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=null, transportSettings=null, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, CollectionCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.client.model.mql.ExpressionCodecProvider@1028a747, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@24890021, com.mongodb.KotlinCodecProvider@613ba54e]}, loggerSettings=LoggerSettings{maxDocumentLength=1000}, clusterSettings={hosts=[localhost:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='15 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=UNSPECIFIED, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, dnsClient=null, inetAddressResolver=null, contextProvider=null}","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:19.272-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=6321800}","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"cluster-ClusterId{value='67509f7fedf9dd162a7a5883', description='null'}-localhost:27017"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:20.381-0300","level":"WARN","message":"\r\n\r\nUsing generated security password: cf7d05dc-43e4-41ab-b957-98955419183d\r\n\r\nThis generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.\r\n","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:20.403-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Global AuthenticationManager configured with UserDetailsService bean with name inMemoryUserDetailsManager","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:21.228-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Exposing 13 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:22.664-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Starting ProtocolHandler [\"http-nio-8080\"]","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:22.698-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:22.727-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Started ErpConnectorVipServiceApplication in 13.701 seconds (process running for 16.559)","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"main"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:38.570-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"http-nio-8080-exec-1"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:38.570-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"http-nio-8080-exec-1"}
    {"timestamp":"2024-12-04T15:29:38.573-0300","level":"INFO","message":"Completed initialization in 2 ms","contextData":null,"extraData":null,"service_name":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","labels.app":"${env:NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}","requestTraceId":"","host":"WNB037675CPS","error.class":"","error.message":"","error.stack":"","subscription":"ABI","threadName":"http-nio-8080-exec-1"}

Does anyone have any clue what I am getting wrong?
It is my first time playing with this sort of update.

i`ll recommend you to provide a full code of test and response. We can't imagine what kind of exception you have.
